# python ftpclient limit connections

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have a bit of a problem with the ftplib from python. It seems that it uses, per default, two connections (one for sending commands, one for datatransfer?). However my ftpserver only accepts one connection at any given time. Since the only file that needs to be transfered is only about 1 MB large, the reasoning of being able to abort inflight commands does not apply here.

Previously the same job was done by the windows commandline ftp client. So I could just call this client from python, but I would really prefer a complete python solution.

Is there a way to tell ftplib, that it should limit itself to a single connection? In filezilla I'm able to "limit the maximum number of simultanious connections", ideally I would like to reproduce this functionality.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that it uses, per default, two connections (one for sending commands, one for datatransfer?).

That's how ftp works. You have a control connection (usually port 21) for commands and a data connection for data transfer, file listing etc and a dynamic port.

> However my ftpserver only accepts one connection at any given time.

ftpserver might have a limit for multiple control connections, but it must still accept data connections. Could you please show from tcpdump, wireshark, logfiles etc why you think multiple connections are the problem?

> In filezilla I'm able to "limit the maximum number of simultanious connections"

This is for the number of control connections only. Does it work with filezilla? Because I doubt that ftplib opens multiple control connections.

Comment: Well the guys programming the sensors told me that they accept only one connection. I simply trusted them, but I will try to get you the wireshark dumps. Yes with filezilla it works just fine. I can also interact with the sensor in a limited way. I.e. I can connect, ask for the welcome message. But if I try to get the list of files (ftp.nlst) it shuts down the connection

Comment: for example when I do: ftp.sendcmd('list') wireshark has an entry "Response: 425 Data connection refused"

Comment: This is very strange. Could you get more debug from ftplibs session or make a packet capture?

Comment: It might also be a problem if you are using active mode and have a firewall in between. Try passive mode.

Comment: In [19]: ftp.sendcmd('list')
*cmd* 'list'
*put* 'list\r\n'
*get* '150 Opening data connection for ls (10.150.1.59,58033)\r\n'
*resp* '150 Opening data connection for ls (10.150.1.59,58033)'
Out[19]: '150 Opening data connection for ls (10.150.1.59,58033)'

Comment: Sry I dont know how to make SO keep the format. There is no firewall between the PC and the sensor. As to the passive mode. I thought I had turned it on, but I will check it again. As to the packet capture, I have to read up first how to do this, sorry.

Comment: If the server sends back "150 Opening data connection..." then you are probably using active mode, where the client sends a PORT or EPRT command with the information where the server should connect to and the server then opens the data connection to the client (please check with debug output). And you get this message from the server because it cannot connect to the client. Are PC and sensor directly connected (and in the same network 10.150.1...) or is there a router or similar in between?

Comment: Hey, we finally figured out where the problem was. Setting the debug output to 2 was the key. The problem was (as you mentioned) the activ mode, which had to be activated manually. Otherwise there would be a connection abort, due to the pasv command being unknown. It was after all not a problem of the amount of connections but one of the used internal commands of the .storbinaries function. Thanks for your help